# Implementing a simple version of Prolog findall without using the built-in findall

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-findall

I am trying to implement a simple version of findall in Prolog without using the built-in findall or similar built-in predicates -- just as a learning exercise.

For example, suppose there is a relation a/1 in my database,

```
a(1).
a(11).
a(13).
```

and I want a relation like find_the_as(List) to give me List = [1,11,13].

I can do this with a "fail" based loop using assert and retract, but I am thinking there must be a recursive way to do this using an accumulator (and I am just not seeing it).

Thanks in advance!

for example:

a(1).
a(11).
a(13).

```
%
% collect all the N such that a(N) 
% into a List
%  
collect_n_such_that_a_of_n(List) :- 
   retractall(the_n_such_that_a_of_n(_)),
   assert(the_n_such_that_a_of_n([])),
   (
      a(N),
      the_n_such_that_a_of_n(As),
      retractall(the_n_such_that_a_of_n(_)),
      assert(the_n_such_that_a_of_n([N|As])),
      fail
   ) ; true,
   the_n_such_that_a_of_n(List).
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this example:

```
a(1).
a(11).
a(13).

find(Input,Input) :- \+ (a(X), \+ memberchk(X,Input)).
find(Input,Output) :- a(X), \+ memberchk(X,Input), !, find([X|Input],Output). 

find_the_as(List) :- find([], List).
```

then the query:

```
find_the_as(List).
```

returns:

```
List = [13, 11, 1]
```

The example uses:

- [memberchk/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=memberchk/2) - True if the first argument is a member of the list represented by the second argument.
- [\+/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%5C%2B/1) - True if the goal represented by its argument cannot be proven.

Unlike with findall, the resulting list does not contain duplicates. eg. if you add an extra `a(11)` then the resulting list will still only contain one `11`.

Unlike with findall, the elements in the resulting list are in reverse order to which they were found (i.e. `[13, 11, 1]` rather than `[1, 11, 13]`).

Answer (score 0):

Using [`call_nth/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call_nth/2) (beware of procedures which have side effects):

```
findall_recursive(Template, Goal, Bag):-
  findall_recursive(Template, Goal, Bag, 1).
  
findall_recursive(Template, Goal, Bag, N) :-
    copy_term(Goal-Template, CGoal-CTemplate),
    (   call_nth(CGoal, N)
    ->  succ(N, N1),
        Bag=[CTemplate|Bag1],
        findall_recursive(Template, Goal, Bag1, N1)
    ;   Bag=[]
    ).
```

Sample run having these facts:

```
a(1).
a(11).
a(13).
a(11).

?- findall_recursive(X, a(X), Bag).
Bag = [1, 11, 13, 11].
```